# dax coding in powerBI to show 1 as Monday and 7 as Sunday as same with others (direct query)

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I want to show 1 as Monday and 7 as Sunday in DAX coding
write now I am using

```
day of the week = WEEKDAY(msg_event[Eventdate],1)
```

this only shows number instead of names like Monday Tuesday etc
Note: Iam using DirectQuery here so some code behave differently/or wont be working

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
day of week = 
var dayNum= WEEKDAY('Calendar'[Date])
var result = SWITCH(
dayNum,
1,"Monday",
2,"Tuesday",
3,"Wednesday",
4,"Thursday",
5,"Friday",
6,"Saturday",
7,"Sunday")
return
result
```